# Why are Android ActionBar methods abstract and where can I find the implementation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

From within my activity I'm running (for example):

```
getActionBar().setTitle("whateverTitle");
```

so I know there is something running, however I cannot find the source code.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html):
 ActionBar extends Object and has no direct subclasses. Also on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ActionBar.java):
 `almost` every method is public abstract.

Where can I find the concrete implementation of `ActionBar`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ususally when I came across these situations, I will do this. call `getActionBar().getClass().getName()`. Now you will get class name qualified with its package(Name of a class that actually implemented `ActionBar`). Now search in Google with that class name. You will find an answer...

Comment: did as instructed and I got com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl same as accepted answer below. Thanks @GopalRao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the class that implements `ActionBar` is `ActionBarImpl`. You can find it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl)

Comment: This might be considered an extra question, but since we're on the topic: Is there a particular reason to make almost every method abstract in ActionBar and implement these in the ActionBarImpl subclass?

Comment: if you decide to subclass, developing your version of ActionBar, you are forced to provide your own implementation of those method. For instance, in  setLogo you will probably looking for a certain ImageView and set an id.. and so on..